# Migrate extension to python3, rich comparison

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I'm trying to migrate a project to Python 3.4 and I'm having trouble understanding and implementing the Python3 rich comparison feature. The project implements a Python extension of a C library

I'm new to Python and it’s been about 15 years since I’ve done any C

I didn't write the original project and it is abandoned. It only had one commit in 2012 and it's based on another Author's work from 2006. However, the project does exactly what I want so I'm keen to revive and update it.

I've been able update the code to build without errors to Python 2.7 and get it running and passing the tests. I've also created a Python 3.4 branch that will now build without errors. This was done by basically looking up each error and warning thrown by the compiler and implementing the recommended fix.

However, when I import the library with Python 3.4 after compiling it like:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> import _suffix_tree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Type _suffix_tree.SuffixTreeNode defines tp_reserved
(formerly tp_compare) but not tp_richcompare. Comparisons may not behave as intended.
```

Looking at the extension there is indeed no tp_richcompare implemenation so I've tried to add it.
I've tried implementing several solutions I've found online but none have worked and I don't know enough about the problem to fix it without help. I've tried implementing the required rich comparison functionality without an success. An example of an attempt I've tried is:

```
static PyObject* Node_richcmp(NodeObject *n1, NodeObject *n2, int op);

static PyObject* Node_richcmp(NodeObject    *n1, NodeObject *n2, int op)
{
    return (int)(n1->node - n2->node);
}

Node_richcmp,                          /* tp_richcompare */
```

However I get errors like:

```
python_bindings.c:218:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  Node_richcmp,         /* tp_richcompare */
  ^
python_bindings.c:218:2: warning: (near initialization for 'NodeType.tp_richcompare') [enabled by default]
python_bindings.c: In function 'Node_richcmp':
python_bindings.c:418:5: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     return (int)(n1->node - n2->node);
     ^
```

Now I'm guessing based on the error and some searching that I'm messing up an assignment of a value VS an address, but I'm not sure  if this is correct or how to go about fixing it.

Can anyone help me implement the required rich comparison method?

I've tried resources like: http://py3c.readthedocs.org/ but I'm just not getting it.

The full code for the project can be found here: https://github.com/mattporritt/suffix-tree-unicode on the python_34 branch

Comment: You are returning an int, but you want a python object. Using `PyLong_FromLong` may do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with ctypes for my solution: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html
I compiled the library as a shared object (.so) and was able to get a basic Python interface up in about 15 mins. All I needed was as an API interface to the c library, so ctypes was exactly what I needed and was easier than CFFI or the original method I was using.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just copy the previous implementation of `tp_compare`. `tp_richcompare` has a [considerably different contract](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare). It (usually) returns `Py_True` or `Py_False` rather than `-1`, `0` or `1` and its return value should depend on the comparison that was requested (`op`).

Comment: You're correct, I  can see that tp_compare: " should return 1 if self greater than other, 0 if self is equal to other, and -1 if self less than other"
and tp_richcompare:"should return the result of the comparison (usually Py_True or Py_False). If the comparison is undefined, it must return Py_NotImplemented, if another error occurred it must return NULL and set an exception condition."

So there is work to be done there, however even cooking it to return False doesn't fix:
    python_bindings.c:218:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Even though you're guaranteed that the first parameter is "an instance of the type that is defined by PyTypeObject", the signature of your function has to be `PyObject *tp_richcompare(PyObject *a, PyObject *b, int op)`. `PyObject* Node_richcmp(NodeObject    *n1, NodeObject *n2, int op)` is more restrictive on the input arguments and thus incompatible.

Comment: Thanks for your patience on this, but I have a feeling I'm out of my depth here.  I'm unable to get it working. I still think the comparison is the root of my issues and I'm now getting the following in Python: SystemError: error return without exception set. Which I'm guessing means exactly what it says for my comparison method.

Comment: If you want to give up porting the old Python-C-bindings of `suffix-tree-unicode`, you can try to instead use that C library from Python through [CFFI](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/). I haven't used it myself yet, but [I've heard](http://www.python-summit.ch/pages/program.html) it's much easier to use than directly writing glue code for the Python C API.